# Maven-ear plugin: could not resolve dependencies to ejbModule

Tags: maven, ejb, ear

I am probably missing something but how is the maven ear plugin (I'm using version 2.5) resolving ejbModule dependencies? I have the following structure:

```
my-parent (multimodule)
-- pom.xml
-- myEar
-----pom.xml
---myEjb
-----pom.xml
```

In the ear I have the dependency to myEjb.

2 things that are unexpected when i execute mvn package under myEar

1. It does not build (package) myEjb.
2. It does try to resolve the depedency to myEjb via repository, which is in our case our custom sonar repository that we configured in settings.xml. I would like not to have to install myEjb to our custom sonar respository in a separate step.

What I expected from the plugin would be: check the ejbModules dependencies, build and package them if not done or something changed, copy the jar to the target directory of the ear project and package the whole thing correctly.

Obviously I am missing something though, anybody can enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your structure you have to build from the root of your project which means you have to change to my-parent directory

```
my-parent (multimodule)
-- pom.xml
-- myEar
-----pom.xml
---myEjb
-----pom.xml
```

and do

```
mvn clean package
```

The behaviour you described that maven tries to solve the dependencies against your local repository is the usual process. You can do partialy building a single module within a multi-module build but in your case this won't work cause you depend on your myEjb which neeeds to be rebuilded. Otherwise you can do a

```
mvn install
```

first and after that you can do from the root:

```
mvn -pl myEjb clean test
```

which will only build the myEjb module and uses the dependencies from the repository (localy in this case).